# What's the max memory SQL Server 2016 Express can use?

Tags: sql-server

I found a Microsoft document on SQL Server 2008 Express giving the hardware limits but am unable to find one on the 2016 version. Is it still 1GB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it should be 1GB.
This is a screenshot from Microsoft official site: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-editions:

[image]

Hope it will help you.